# how to bind blur and focus events to ajax combobox

Tags: jquery

I have tried something of this sort

```
$('#<%= txtSponsorBC2.ClientID %>').focus(function () {
        var selectedDate = $('#txtMandateDate').datepicker('getDate');
        var currentDate = new Date();
        currentDate.setHours(0);
        currentDate.setMinutes(0);
        currentDate.setSeconds(0);


        if ($("#txtMandateDate").val() != "" && $("#txtMandateDate").val() != "dd/mm/yyyy") {
            if (Date.parse(selectedDate) < currentDate) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert(" date cannot be future date");
                return false;
            }
        }

    });
```

If I use  `$('#<%= txtSponsorBC2.ClientID %>')` to access ajax combobox i get an error

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= txtSponsorBC2.ClientID %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#'+<%= txtSponsorBC2.ClientID %>)` instead